# Series of complex numbers convergence

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the domain of absolute convergence for:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{((n+1)!)^2(z-2)^{2n}} {(2n+1)!(2n)} $$

which test should be used in this case?

I thought about using the root test, but it creates a problem since there is factorial in both numerator and denominator.

Using the ratio test:

$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{((n+2)!)^2(z-2)^{2n+2}} {(2n+3)!(2n+2)} \frac {(2n+1)!(2n)} {((n+1)!)^2(z-2)^{2n}} $ =
$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{((n+2)!)^2(z-2)^2} {(2n+3)(2n+2)(2n+2)} \frac {(2n)} {((n+1)!)^2} $ =
$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(z-2)^2(2n)} {(2n+3)} $

We have $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(2n)} {(2n+3)} = 1 $
The condition becomes
$ {(z-2)^2} < {1} $
therefore
$ |z-2| < 1 $
$ (x-2)^2 + y^2 < 1 $

Kind of stuck at this point. Any advice?

Comment: $|z-2|<1$ is the solution. You're done!

Comment: Ok thank you. And the domain in this case is the inside of the circle centered at (2,0) with radius 1, correct?

Comment: yes, exactly.${}$